# Single Linked List Python Header and Tail

Tags: python

I'm learning Python coming from C++ and I'm not sure why my insert method in class LinkedList is not working. I'm expecting my Header node to be linked to my Tail Node, but I'm not getting the expected behavior.

```
class Node:
    value = None
    nextNode = None

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = None

class LinkedList:

    head = Node()
    tail = Node()

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = Node()

    #insert a node method
    def insert(self, value):
        #if new list
        if self.head == None:
            newNode = Node(value)
            self.head = newNode
            newNode.nextNode = self.tail
        else:
            newNode = Node(value)
            self.tail.nextNode = newNode
            self.tail = newNode
            newNode.nextNode = self.head



list1 = LinkedList()
list1.insert(23)
list1.insert(50)
print(list1.head.nextNode.value) #Expect this to be 50, but this returns None
```

Comment: Replace `== None` with `is None`

Comment: @Minn while that is more idiomatic they are technically equivalent

Comment: The node your are calling `tail` never has a value assigned to it. Try giving it a value: `self.tail = Node('tail')`

Comment: @Minn While perhaps being a best practice, your suggestion makes no difference to the behavior of the OP's code.

Comment: Are you trying to insert new node as a head or a tail?

Comment: You aren't updating your `.tail` in your `if` block correctly, for starters. Note, stop making class level variables, they are totally pointless, you always shadow them with your instance variables.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think a non-node sentinel object like `None` would be more idiomatic

Comment: I totally agree @juanpa.arrivillaga — I was just pointing out why it was printing None. Maintaining a reference to the tail node is fine, but its nextValue should be None if it's the last thing in the chain. The code above makes a loop back to head for some reason.

Comment: You aren't actually using the class attributes; removing them will not affect the instance attributes of the same name.

Comment: @MarkMeyer attempting to create a circular linked list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to insert a new node as a tail then try this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = new_node
        elif self.tail:
            self.tail.nextNode = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.head.nextNode = new_node
            self.tail = new_node


list1 = LinkedList()
list1.insert(23)
list1.insert(50)
list1.insert(40)
list1.insert(99)

node = list1.head
print('(head)', end=' -> ')
while node:
    print(node.value, end=' -> ')
    node = node.nextNode
print('(tail)')
```

```
(head) -> 23 -> 50 -> 40 -> 99 -> (tail)
```

No need to use class variables.

Comment: @Mark Meyer, edited, I used `next` instead of `nextNode` on one of the node.

Comment: Still doesn't work with more than two. The tail is pointing to the second node.

Answer (score 2):

The class is much simpler with a sentinel, but the *head* should be the sentinel.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(0)  # Store the length, or any other metadata you like
        self.tail = self.head  # The tail is just the last item.

    # the list is empty when the head and the tail are the same
    # node (namely, the sentinel)
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.tail is self.head

    def insert(self, value):
        """Add a value to the end of the list"""
        new_node = Node(value)
        self.tail.next = new_node  # Append the node
        self.tail = new_node  # Advance the tail
        self.head.value += 1  # Update the length
```

And that's all you need. The list maintains two invariants: the head always refers to a sentinel node, and the tail always refers to the last element of the list. Appending to the list just means appending a node after the tail, then updating the tail.

The purpose of the head is to provide an entry point for iterating over the list. The tail is a convenience, to make appending to the end of the list an O(1) operation, rather than having to spend O(n) time iterating from the head to find the last node.

---

A few exercises:

1. Write `LinkedList.__len__`, so you can retrieve the length of a list with `len(ll)`
2. Your `insert` should really be called `append`. Write a "real" `insert` method that takes a position to indicate where the new node should be inserted. (`ll.insert(0, x)` would create a new first element, and `ll.insert(n, x)` would insert a new element after the `n-1` element.)
3. Write `LinkedList.delete` to delete an element at the specified position. `ll.delete(0)` would remove the first element of `ll`. Note that this should never remove the sentinel, i.e., it's a no-op if `ll.is_empty()` returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this looks a lot cleaner. One thing that i couldn't understand is how the head's next pointer is getting updated. 
To clarify, initially linked list is 0 --> None, where 0 is both the head and tail and they both point to None. Now, while appending a new node (1st time), we have updated the next pointer of current tail and set that new node as new tail. I couldn't find anywhere the head's next getting updated and pointing to the new value. I thought 0 would still point to None, but actually while logging the program the pointer is getting updated. I am very confused..

Comment: `head` *doesn't* get updated. You're appending to the *end* of the list, which doesn't affect the *front* of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have an elif or the tail.

```
class Node:
    value = None
    nextNode = None

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = None

class LinkedList:

    head = Node()

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    #insert a node method
    def insert(self, value):
        #if new list
        newNode = Node(value)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            #save head's current position
            temp = self.head
            #move head's position until you find a None value for
            #nextNode
            while(temp.nextNode):
                temp = temp.nextNode

            #set the none value to the new node
            temp.nextNode = newNode

    list1 = LinkedList()
    list1.insert(23)
    list1.insert(50)
    list1.insert(50)
    list1.insert(70)
    print(list1.head.value)
    #23
    print(list1.head.nextNode.value)
    #50
    print(list1.head.nextNode.nextNode.value)
    #50
    print(list1.head.nextNode.nextNode.nextNode.value)
    #70
```